# Run VMware Player on CentOS 6

Tags: windows, linux, cloud, vmware-player

I am trying to run VMware Player on CentOS 6. I am stuck with the following issue after installing the VMware Player package. VMware Player fails to start and gives the following error message.

`Virtual machine monitor    [FAILED]`

While trying to query the status of VMware Player, the following does not load

`Module vmmon not loaded`

I am at my wits end after trying to resolve this. Please let me know your suggestions and advice. Your help is very much appreciated.

This question has been closed on both the stackoverflow and serverfault sites saying "Off Topic". I hope this is the place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Please check on the following to resolve the issue.

- Make sure your kenel-headers is installed matching to your running kernel.
- Remove the old binary modules: 
   mv /usr/lib/vmware/modules/binary /usr/lib/vmware/modules/binary.old
- Rebuild it again: vmware-modconfig –console –install-all

  Chakri -

Comment: tried matching
# rpm -q kernel-devel
kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64
# rpm -q kernel-headers
kernel-headers-2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64
# uname -r
2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: when vmware-modconfig –console –install-all is done it completes a build but the virtual monitor still fails to load.

Comment: tried #service vmware status

Module vmmon not loaded
Module vmnet loaded

Comment: When i try this the output is an error
# modprobe vmmon
FATAL: Error inserting vmmon (/lib/modules/2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64/misc/vmmon.ko): Invalid module format